# Adding lxd containers on Windows 10 hyper V host networking issue

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, lxc, lxd, hyper-v

While creating LXD containers on Ubuntu 16.04 sitting on Windows 10 Hyper V having external virtual switch network configuration, containers do not get connected with the external network. All the requests are only forwarded to the host and the host does not forward to the external network.

What am I missing in the configuration? Or is it a limitation in the Hyper V?

PS: Ubuntu on the Hyper V has the exact same configuration of a normal Ubuntu Server having containers. Bridged LXC containers.

[image: Virtual switch network configuration Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to Tick 'Enable Mac Address Spoofing' un 'Advanced Features' in the network adapter settings

https://www.technibble.com/forums/threads/start-using-containers-on-ubuntu.74887/

This has been plaguing me for years.